# How to query Firestore based on item similarity

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, recommendation-engine

I am creating a simple recommendation system that uses Firebase. The system matches users based on biographical data (e.g. gender, age, height, etc), which is stored in Firestore.

Given a query user, I want to compute a similarity score between this user and the other users. From this score, I want to retrieve all users and their corresponding scores above a score threshold and order them by their scores (descending).

I know how to query Firestore using standard `.where()` and `.orderBy()` clauses but I don't know how to use these clauses with per-item computed values. Can this be done with a Firestore query alone, or do I need to make use of Cloud Functions or some other solution?

Comment: I don't fully understand what do you mean "per-item computed values". Can you provide simple example?

Comment: In my case, the per-item computed values are the scores, with each matched user having a score. Given a query user, I want the matched users to be ordered by their similarity to the query user. The computed values (scores) are dynamic -- they depend on the user given as input to the query.

Comment: Generally it should be possible with no problem. Have you tried something already? Please publish your try code and share problems you are facing.